# 404 Error when attempting to update Firebase Cloud Firestore database

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a Firestore database like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSZ8m.png)

My code intends to update the fields "intensity" and "seconds" (under the document "1", under collection "Event") with the value "test" and 123 respectively.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Initialize Firebase admin
cred = credentials.Certificate('taiwaneew-firebase-adminsdk-odl9d-222bd18a4e.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://taiwaneew.firebaseio.com/'
})

# Define a function to send data to the Firebase database
def send_data(param1, param2):
    ref = db.reference(path='/TaiwanEEW/Event/1')
    ref.update({
        'intensity': param1,
        'seconds': param2
    })

# Invoke our function to send data to Firebase
send_data("test", 123)
```

The code, however, causes the following error:

```
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 929, in request
        return super(_Client, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 119, in request
        resp.raise_for_status()
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://taiwaneew.firebaseio.com/TaiwanEEW/Event/1.json?print=silent

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/eewPush.py", line 20, in <module>
        send_data("777", 778)
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/eewPush.py", line 14, in send_data
        ref.update({
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 341, in update
        self._client.request('patch', self._add_suffix(), json=value, params='print=silent')
    File "/Users/joelin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 931, in request
        raise _Client.handle_rtdb_error(error)
firebase_admin.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Not Found
```

I have tried to identify the cause of error but the same error persists. I would really like to hear some opinions if you have any experiences on this. Thank you so much!

I have double checked that my credentials json file is correct, under the same directory as the python file, and my database premissions to write and read set to true.

I tried both '/TaiwanEEW/Event/1' and '/taiwaneew/Event/1' for the reference path because I am not sure if it should be the project name or the database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coud not find the error here, so I come with a workaround.

You can use `firebase_admin.firestore`.

Then, your `db` object will be instanciated by `db = firestore.client()`, and have access to all collections and document (see [doc](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/client)).

---

Complete solution:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore


cred = credentials.Certificate('taiwaneew-firebase-adminsdk-odl9d-222bd18a4e.json')
# no need for an url here if your credentials already contain the project id.
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred) 
db = firestore.client()


# Define a function to send data to the Firebase database
def send_data(param1, param2):
    doc = db.document('Event/1') # or doc = db.collection('Event').document('1')
    doc.update({
        'intensity': param1,
        'seconds': param2
    })

# Invoke our function to send data to Firebase
send_data("test", 123)
```